# What would prevent Visual Studio/WCF from generating a new updated WSDL after adding new service methods?

Tags: wcf

I had a long post here about how I was adding web methods and they were not being reflected in the generated wsdl.

It turns out the code I was using as a starting point had the configuration manager set to release.  And I was busy running the debug version which of course was not being updated.

Comment: I hope answering your own question isn't bad form but I wasted time I didn't have trying to figure this out. If I save someone else a few minutes ...

Comment: It is not bad at all to answer your own question, but it would be better to post it as a real answer, and accept that answer, so this question will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the code I was using as a starting point had the configuration manager set to release. And I was busy running the debug version which of course was not being updated.